# How to Group and get Count using morphia in mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm using Morphia with MongoDB in Java, and i have collection like this

```
{"_id":"5d5e7ce7869eef030869e85c",
    "ip":"66.249.79.181",
    "date":"2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url":"https://www.example.com/home", 
    "status_code":"200", 
    "bot":"Google Android",
    "type":"type/html",
    "domain":"https://www.example.com"},

{"_id":"5d5e7ce7869eef030869e85c",
    "ip":"66.249.79.181",
    "date":"2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url":"https://www.example.com/home", 
    "status_code":"200", 
    "bot":"Google",
    "type":"type/html",
    "domain":"https://www.example.com"},

{"_id":"5d5e7ce7869eef030869e85c",
    "ip":"66.249.79.181",
    "date":"2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url":"https://www.example.com/home", 
    "status_code":"200", 
    "bot":"bing",
    "type":"type/html",
    "domain":"https://www.example.com"}
```

i need to using grouping("request_url") and get count of "bot" field what if I need result like this

```
{"request_url":"https://www.example.com/home",
 "status_code":"200",
 "Google": 1,
 "Google Android": 1,
 "bing": 1,
 "type":"type/html", }
```

How can i do this group by "request_url" Field and get Count of each "bot" Field have

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregate below as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        request_url: "$request_url",
        bot: "$bot"
      },
      type: {
        $max: "$type"
      },
      status_code: {
        $max: "$status_code"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.request_url",
      type: {
        $max: "$type"
      },
      status_code: {
        $max: "$status_code"
      },
      counts: {
        $push: {
          bot: "$_id.bot",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Giving input:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "66.249.79.181",
    "date": "2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url": "https://www.example.com/home",
    "status_code": "200",
    "bot": "Google Android",
    "type": "type/html",
    "domain": "https://www.example.com"
  },
  {
    "ip": "66.249.79.181",
    "date": "2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url": "https://www.example.com/home",
    "status_code": "200",
    "bot": "Google",
    "type": "type/html",
    "domain": "https://www.example.com"
  },
  {
    "ip": "66.249.79.181",
    "date": "2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url": "https://www.example.com/home",
    "status_code": "200",
    "bot": "bing",
    "type": "type/html",
    "domain": "https://www.example.com"
  }
]
```

And output being:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "https://www.example.com/home",
    "counts": [
      {
        "bot": "bing",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "bot": "Google",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "bot": "Google Android",
        "count": 1
      }
    ],
    "status_code": "200",
    "type": "type/html"
  }
]
```

Comment: He specified "using morphia".

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "request_url":"$request_url",
                "bot":"$bot"
            },
            "request_url":{
                $first:"$request_url"
            },
            "k":{
                $first:"$bot"
            },
            "v":{
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$request_url",
            "request_url":{
                $first:"$request_url"
            },
            "bots":{
                $push:{
                    "k":"$k",
                    "v":"$v"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "info.request_url":"$request_url",
            "bots":{
                $arrayToObject:"$bots"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "info":{
                $mergeObjects:["$info","$bots"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            newRoot:"$info"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d0f456bc2ad3b23f7dfcf"),
    "ip" : "66.249.79.181",
    "date" : "2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url" : "https://www.example.com/home",
    "status_code" : "200",
    "bot" : "Google Android",
    "type" : "type/html",
    "domain" : "https://www.example.com"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d0f456bc2ad3b23f7dfd0"),
    "ip" : "66.249.79.181",
    "date" : "2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url" : "https://www.example.com/home",
    "status_code" : "200",
    "bot" : "Google",
    "type" : "type/html",
    "domain" : "https://www.example.com"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d0f456bc2ad3b23f7dfd1"),
    "ip" : "66.249.79.181",
    "date" : "2019-08-19T18:30:00.000Z",
    "request_url" : "https://www.example.com/home",
    "status_code" : "200",
    "bot" : "bing",
    "type" : "type/html",
    "domain" : "https://www.example.com"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "request_url" : "https://www.example.com/home",
    "bing" : 1,
    "Google" : 1,
    "Google Android" : 1
}
```

**Explanation:** The data is grouped on the `request_url` and distinct key-value pairs are calculated. The key(k) would hold the bot name and the value(v) would hold the occurrence count. Later on, each pair is pushed into an array and then the array is converted into an object.

Comment: He specified "using morphia".